# How to pipe data to rapper (command-line RDF parser by Redland)

Tags: pipe, rdf, redland

How does one pipe data to rapper (command-line RDF parser by Redland)?
The following does not work:

```
curl "http://download.lodlaundromat.org/85d5a476b56fde200e770cefa0e5033c" | gunzip | rapper
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rapper supports this, though it is pretty undocumented.
To stream results to rapper, add `-` as argument, and add a base uri. I.e., your command should be:

```
curl "http://download.lodlaundromat.org/85d5a476b56fde200e770cefa0e5033c" | gunzip | rapper -i ntriples - http://baseuri
```

Comment: Rapper author here.  Yes undocumented and I can fix that but even in other tools, on Linux you can always use a file /dev/fd/0 or /dev/stdin when the magic '-' isn't available.

Comment: Is there a proper documentation of how to use the raptor library and what are the perquisite libraries ?? I looked into the main site but its really confusing on how to get started...